# how to select the strings with indefinite values?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to remove string after . including ., but length is variable and string can be of any length.

1)Example:
Input:-

> SCC0204, FRK0005.C, AQTY0908, RF0023.A, ADF1010.X, HGT9010.X,
>   AOPLY082, BNMY908.X, TRYU0921

Output:

> SCC0204, AQTY0908,  AOPLY082,  TRYU0921

I want to select string that do not have '.% ' extension.

the length of the string changes and its not fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
select urcolum from table where urcolum not like '%.%'
```

Comment: how do i do it using a case statement.

Comment: you can do something like case when urcolum not like '%.%' then urcolum else null end